# Search suggestions on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, here-api

I am working on a Here Maps based web application.

I'd like to implement its search suggestions feature to an `<input type="text" />`which is an input to plan directions.

I'd like to have the search suggestions appear on jQuery's `keyup event`, in the same manner that google maps has.

This is my code so far:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="waypoints[]" id="waypoint-1" class="waypoint" />
```

A basic jQuery keyup event handler

```
$('.waypoint').on('keyup', function () {

});
```

And here's the code that I should use, found in the [documentation](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics/places-search.html) and the [api explorer](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer)

```
var searchBox = new nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox ({
    targetNode: 'waypoint-1',
    searchCenter: function () {
        return {
            latitude: 52.516274,
            longitude: 13.377678
        }
    },
    onResults: function (data) {
        console.log(data.results.items);
    }
});
```

How can I display search suggestions every time the user releases a key? Where should I put the SearchBox's code in my event handler to respond to that event? Whats the `searchCenter` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript `SearchBox` can act as an all-in-one Widget, you don't need to add extra events to handle the key presses. You can initialise it as you have shown, but you'll need to ensure that the `targetNode` matches the `id` of a `<DIV>` already present in the DOM. e.g you could use `targetNode = waypoint1` if you include the following

```
<div id="waypoint1" class="main-search">
  <span class ="caption">Start:</span>
  <div module="SearchBox">
    <input rel="searchbox-input" class="search-box-bckgrnd" type="text" />
    <div rel="searchbox-list" class="search-list"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A working routing example can be found in the [HERE Maps Community Examples](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#directions-rendering-component__suggestion-box-with-directions).

The `searchCenter` helps to define the location context of the search - it is better described in the [RESTful Places Documentation](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places/topics/location-contexts.html). Specifically it maps onto the `at` parameter. The other alternative is to attach the widget to an associated map which will supply an `in` parameter instead. Note that the Widget only starts to give suggestions after typing at least three characters.

It is of course possible to build up your own Widget from scratch using JQuery - just use keyup, create a REST request using the [suggest endpoint](http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/suggest?app_id=demo_qCG24t50dHOwrLQ&app_code=NYKC67ShPhQwqaydGIW4yg&at=52.521,13.3807&q=Brandenb) and parse the resultant String array into a drop-down of your choice.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot! Sadly, Here Maps' documentation has lots of room for improvement.